# Next in the number sequence problem: 20, 21, 33, 68, 172.5, 520.5

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence

*20, 21, 33, 68, 172.5, 520.5, ?*

What will come next in this number sequence problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next number in the sequence is

> 1825.25

Reasoning

> (20 x **1.0**) + **1.0** = 21
>  (21 x **1.5**) + **1.5** = 33
>  (33 x **2.0**) + **2.0** = 68
>  (68 x **2.5**) + **2.5** = 172.5
>  (172.5 x **3.0**) + **3.0** = 520.5
>  (520.5 x **3.5**) + **3.5** = 1825.25